# Count Filtered Items between values

Tags: angularjs

I am showing hotels of a list. if a filter checkbox is checked, result list change according to the selection criteria.

My **Controller** data looks like this:

```
$scope.hotels= [
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'HOTELONE',
  fname: 'Tony',
  lname: 'Stark',
  location: 'Stark Tower',
  rate: '250.00'
},
{
  id: 2,
  name: 'HOTELTWO',
  fname: 'Bruce',
  lname: 'Wayne',
  location: 'Bat Cave',
  rate: '500.00'
},];

$scope.getPriceRange = function (pricefrom,priceto) {
    return filterFilter($scope.hotels, { rate: pricefrom && priceto}).length;
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="pull-right">
   <p class="ng-binding">[{{getPriceRange("100","300")}}]</p>
</div>
```

How do i filter hotels between rate values?.

Comment: You can use **ng-if**, instead calling a function

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: @NNR. thanks.I can use **ng-if**. but how can i filer between values?

Comment: ng-if="hotel.rate > 100 && hotel.rate < 300"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing an *object* to `filterFilter`, pass a *function* that checks that the rate is in the range:

```
return filterFilter($scope.hotels, function(hotel){
   // calculation
   return hotel.rate >= pricefrom && hotel.rate <= priceto
}).length;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.hotels= [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'HOTELONE',
    fname: 'Tony',
    lname: 'Stark',
    location: 'Stark Tower',
    rate: '250.00'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'HOTELTWO',
    fname: 'Bruce',
    lname: 'Wayne',
    location: 'Bat Cave',
    rate: '500.00'
}];

$scope.copyObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.hotels));

$scope.getPriceRange = function(startPrice, endPrice) {
  $scope.hotels = $scope.copyObj.filter(item => { return item.rate >= startPrice && item.rate <= endPrice });
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="checkbox" name="range" ng-model="priceRange" ng-change="getPriceRange(100,300)"/>100-300<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="range" ng-model="priceRange1" ng-change="getPriceRange(400,800)"/>400-800<hr>
  <div ng-repeat="item in hotels">
    <p>{{item.name}}</p>
    <p>{{item.rate}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
app.filter('myFormat', function() {
    return function(x) {
        var i,count=0,
while(i>200 && i<500){
count++
}
return count;
        
});
```

```html
try to render a numbers  array which should contain all numbers 

  <li ng-repeat="x in numbers">
        {{x | myFormat}}
    </li>
```